# Thousands of reader/writer locks in a single process

Tags: c++, c, synchronization, cross-platform, semaphore

I am currently designing a C++ cross-platform (Linux/Windows) server application with a large-scale synchronization pattern. I internally use boost::thread as an abstraction of the OS-specific threads. My problem is to protect an array of data, **each element of the array being protected by an independent reader/writer lock**.

My array contains **4096 elements**. Considering the solution of the "writer-priority readers-writers" problem that is presented in the "[Little Book of Semaphores](http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/)" (page 85), my application would need 5 semaphores per array element. This gives a total of about 20000 semaphores (or, equivalently, 20000 mutexes + 20000 condition variables).

An additional specificity of my application is that a given time, most semaphores are not active (there is typically about 32 "client" threads waiting/signaling on the thousands of semaphores). Note that since the entire server runs in a single process, I use lightweight, thread-based semaphores (*not* interprocess semaphores).

My question is twofold:

1. Is it recommended to create a total of **20000 semaphores on Linux and on Windows** for a single process? Well, of course, I guess this is not the case...
2. If this practice is not recommended, what technique could I use to reduce the number of actual semaphores, e.g. to create a **set of N "emulated semaphores" on the top of 1 actual semaphore**? I suppose that this would be an interesting solution, because most of my semaphores are inactive at a given time.

Thanks in advance!

### Summary of the answers so far

1. Using thousands of semaphores is **not recommended**, especially from a cross-platform perspective. And so, even if they are not interprocess semaphores (they still consume handles under Windows).
2. A direct way to solve my problem is to split my array into e.g. 64 subarrays of 16 elements, and to **associate each of these subarrays with a single read/write lock**. Unfortunately, this introduces much contention (1 writer would block the reads to 15 elements).
3. Digging into Boost source code, I have found that:

   - The implementation of "boost::mutex" does not wrap CRITICAL_SECTION objects under Windows (but CreateEvent and ReadWriteBarrier),
   - "boost::shared_mutex" uses CreateSemaphore under Windows (which are heavyweight, interprocess objects) , and
   - "boost::shared_mutex" does not wrap "pthread_rwlock_t" under Linux.

   The reasons for this do not seem clear to me. In particular, the use of interprocess objects for "boost::shared_mutex" under Windows seems sub-optimal to me.

### Summary of the open questions so far

1. How can I create a set of N "emulated semaphores" on the top of 1 actual semaphore, keeping the contention between the emulated semaphores as small as possible?
2. How do "boost::mutex" and "boost::shared_mutex" compare with their native counterparts (CRITICAL_SECTION and pthread_rwlock_t)?

Comment: Note that I am aware of the existence of boost::shared_mutex (I could use one shared_mutex per element of the array). However, the underlying implementation would still involve thousands of mutexes and condition variables.

Comment: Without knowing the actual data you are trying to protect from being touched by multiple things, it is quite difficult to answer this question. Since we know nothing about the data structures or even your problem domain, there isn't much I can say besides: You should seriously consider *why* and *how* you need to protect the data before going overboard on locking. You might not even need "semaphores" or to lock the data at all.

Comment: Well, I have tried to write my question in the most general way. To be more specific, my application is a cache system for scientific computations (in the FEM field). The elements of the array correspond to the cache pages. Each cache page stores one computation context about a part of the FEM mesh. The computation context can be stored to the disk. Reading it back into memory requires quite a large setup fee, so I want to keep it as long as possible in memory, so the need for a cache.

Comment: In my opinion, as long as you keep the critical section short, you can as well use a single critical section for the array. Or, if you fear lock congestion, split the array in a few sub-arrays. Critical sections work amazingly well for reasonable concurrency. boost::asio is based on completion ports IIRC, so the no. of concurrent threads _will be_ reasonable (unless you botch with it). A completion port serves about 500k events per second on my machine with 4 concurrent readers, not truly a challenge for a critical section (which can do 10s of millions no problem).

Answer (score 1):

1. This is not recommended. You should not do this actually because
   in Windows it would consume 1 Handle Object per Semaphore. A process
   can only manage a specific amount of Handles objects. Thread/Process
   and other Windows objects may need to use Handle objects and will
   get crashed if they can't. This is similar in Linux with the
   file-descriptor concept.
2. Split your 4096 elements into 30 (for example) sets of 140
   elements and assign to each 140-group a single Semaphore. Then 30
   (in this example) threads will try to access to those 30 sets and
   they will get sinchronized based on each 140-group-Semaphore.

Comment: You confuse between different handle types in windows. THere's no implicit limitation on **kernel** handles. Try creating 10^6 events, and you'll see it's ok. OTOH you may get troubles with too many gdi/user handles

Comment: P.S. *The per-process limit on kernel handles is 2^24*. From here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Hi valdo, Handles in Windows consume memory, you can see more details in the following page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724517(v=vs.85).aspx  ("The total number of open handles in the system is limited only by the amount of memory available. Some object types support a limited number of handles per session or per process")

Comment: Valdo. That Microsoft link you sent is really good. Please note what that article states: "However, handles are stored in the paged pool, so the actual number of handles you can create is based on available memory.". I would avoid creating tons of Handles in my system.

Comment: @Damiox: Thank you much. I will probably stick to your proposal for a first rough implementation (associate a single boost::shared_mutex to several cells of my large array). However, this introduces much more contention than required (a writer on 1 element would block the reads to 139 elements, considering your example). This is problematic, since in my case, a "write" can take much more time than a "read".

Comment: @Tisys: I think it's a good way where you can start from, and learn about its performance. Your post question is really interesting. Good luck with that!

Answer (score 1):

I'll tell you what I think about it from the Windows perspective. I'm very experienced in writing server applications for Windows.

First, there's absolutely no problem to create 20k semaphores for a single process. It's a pretty lightweight kernel object. Even "inter-process" semaphores.

I see however another issue with your design. You should know that **every** operation you do on a kernel object (such as semaphore/mutex) involves a heavy kernel-mode transaction (a.k.a. system call). Every such a call may cost you around 2k CPU cycles, even if there're no collisions at all.

So that you may find yourself i a situation where most of the processor time is spent in just invocation of the synchronization methods.

In contrary in order to synchronize threads one may use interlocked operations. They cost much less (tens of CPU cycles typically).

There's also an object called *critical section*. It's a sort of the hybrid of the interlocked operand and a kernel object (which is used if there's an actual collision). You should check for how long do you typically lock your elements. If it's usually a short-duration locks - just use the critical sections, forget about sophisticated read-write locks.

If nevertheless you deal with long-duration locks, and you **do** need a read-write lock, and you see that you spend a lot of CPU in the kernel-mode transaction - consider creating your own (or try to find an existing) hybrid-like implementation of such a lock.

Comment: Thank for your answer. However, I am using boost::thread mutexes, that are wrappers around Win32's CRITICAL_SECTION objects (and not around kernel mutex objects): http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Thread-win32-msvc-Mutexes-td2577038.html . So I think the performance issues you mention will not be present in my case.

Comment: @Tisys: yes, probably you won't get perf issues with boost::thread mutexes. Just make sure all other synchronization objects involved (at least those that are involved always, regardless to the collisions) are not pure kernel objects as well.

Comment: Checking in boost::thread source code, the implementation of boost::mutex is **not** a wrapper around CRITICAL_SECTION as I have always thought (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/boost/thread/win32/basic_timed_mutex.hpp). The actual implementation mixes calls to "CreateEvent()" and to "ReadWriteBarrier()".

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you should definitively not implement the locks yourself but use `posix_rwlock_t`.

Having an array of `4096` such elements shouldn't present any particular problem. POSIX lock structures are implemented quite efficiently in Linux. In particular they use atomic operations when possible on the "fast path" and only go into system calls (notably for a FUTEX) when there is congestion on that particular lock. So if you implement relatively carefully such that any thread only holds 1 or 2 locks at a time, the constraint on Linux would only be given by your total number of worker threads and not by the number of objects themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Inspecting the boost::thread source code, the "boost::shared_mutex" is indeed *not* a wrapper around "posix_rwlock_t" as I have always thought, but a custom implementation (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/thread/pthread/shared_mutex.hpp). I don't know which implementation is better, but care is to be taken at this point.